# Scroll page after post back

Tags: c#, webforms

I would like to scroll the page down after post back. The code doesn't work with / without the Update Panel.

**Error in Browser console:**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    VM465:1

When clicked on VM465:1, it points to this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 1600 }, 'slow');</script>
```

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnMore" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnMore" runat="server" OnClick="btnMore_Click">ShowMore</asp:LinkButton>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**C#:**

```
protected void btnMore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string message = "alert('Hello!')";
        //ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(sender as Control, this.GetType(), "alert", message, true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(sender as Control, this.GetType(), "ScrollPage", GetPageScrollScript(900), true);
    }

private string GetPageScrollScript(int heightToScroll)
    {
        string ScrollPage = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: " + heightToScroll + " }, 'slow');</script>";
        return ScrollPage;
    }
```

The alert works when I uncomment (wihth and without updatepanel).
What should be done to make the scroll work.

**UPDATE:**
It worked for me this way:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(sender as System.Web.UI.Control, this.GetType(), "ScrollPage", "$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: " + 1000 + " }, 'slow')", true);
```

Comment: jQuery probably isn’t available at that point. Check for JavaScript errors in the browser’s console.

Comment: jQuery is available when I check in console. No other errors.

Comment: Have you tried setting MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" for the page / pages, or setting that in the postback method like Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;?

Comment: @poke. Sorry, there's an error in console. Updated my question.

Comment: @Janne Matikainen .Yes. That did not work.

Comment: I don’t think you should include the `<script…></script>` tags in the output

Comment: you might want to read this: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2010/07/jquery-does-not-work-properly-after.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the alert like

```
alert('Hello!')
```

And that is working, but for the script you want to execute you wrap it around  tags

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: " + heightToScroll + " }, 'slow');</script>
```

try without them?

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: " + heightToScroll + " }, 'slow')
```